# php mail function won't support BCC

Tags: php, html, email

I am using A php mail function script. The script is with attachment support. I want to use BCC in my php mail function that supports attachment(s). 
But dont know how, i've tried to paste:

- `$headers .= 'Bcc: hereyourmail@example.com, hereyourmail@example.com, hereyourmail@example.com' . "\r\n";`

but with no succes.

I still can't figure it out where/how i can support BCC in this code.

Source code:

```
<?php 
//define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'hereyourmail@example.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: hereyourmail@example.com\r\nReply-To: hereyourmail@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('Hereyourfile.pdf'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

// This part of body msg is unnecessary 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Here you can put some html text or code!</h2> 
<p>Here you can put some html text or code!.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Hereyourfile.pdf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Mail BCC not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214935/php-mail-bcc-not-working)

Comment: Any errors in your mail log?

Comment: Really a duplicate. Don't feed, mark the duplicated post. He spend more time in answer than he will spent in searching inside stackoverflow.